# No PowerShell in System.Management.Automation?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, .net-3.5

I'm having trouble getting the `PowerShell` class to resolve. I'm following along with the example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712196/run-pscmdlets-in-c-sharp-code-citrix-xendesktop).

I have a reference added to `System.Management.Automation` from `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\System.Management.Automation.dll`

I have `using System.Management.Automation;` included at the top of my class.

However, when I try to create an instance of powershell: `PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create()`, `PowerShell` won't resolve.

Using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to auto-add the fully-qualified namespace (or using statement) just suggests `Microsoft.Powershell` in place of `PowerShell`.

I'm very confused why this is happening as even the example included in the [MSDN documentation on the PowerShell class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has pretty much exactly what I have.

I am in .NET 3.5, Visual Studio 2010, and Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: What version of Windows are you on? I'm going to guess you're on Windows XP.

Comment: @x0n Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

The PowerShell class is new to PowerShell 2.0.  Make sure you're referencing the 2.0 version of SMA.dll.  Do you have PowerShell 2.0 installed?

Comment: Thats what I initially thought which prompted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053786/2-0-version-of-system-management-automation). I do have 2.0 installed though

Comment: Just to check, does this line run without error `$ps = [powershell]::Create()`?

Comment: It does. Also, just FYI I referenced [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825585/how-to-determine-what-version-of-powershell-is-installed) to check my version. `$psversiontable.psversion` gives me Major: 2, Minor 0, Build -1, Revision -1 (Whats with the negative build and revision numbers?)

Comment: You must be adding a reference to the 1.0 version of SMA.  I would look around on your system for other versions of the assembly.  Try looking under Program Files (x86) (if you're on a 64-bit machine).

Comment: Keith, I hate to conclude the question this way, but I opened up the project again this morning and `PowerShell` is now resolving. This is with the SMA assembly in the GAC, which I DID try yesterday. I really hate when the conclusion to a question is as inconclusive as this... maybe I just had too much coffee. Who knows. I appreciate your help though.