# 2.0 version of System.Management.Automation?

Tags: c#, powershell, gac

Is there a 2.0 (or greater) version of the `System.Management.Automation` assembly?

I'm looking at the [`PowerShell`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class in C# which says that this class was introduced with `PowerShell 2.0`. Does that version number correspond with the version number I'm seeing when I add the reference to the assembly in Visual Studio?

This is kind of an additional question to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051184/no-powershell-in-system-management-automation) which is in regards to having trouble resolving the `PowerShell` class inside that assembly.

I've tried the `System.Management.Automation` assembly in both the GAC:

```
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35
```

And `Reference Assemblies`:

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

Both containing folders only have version 1.0

I have PowerShell 2.0 installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The strong name version for both powershell v1 and powershell v2 is `1.0.0.0`. Surprising, yes, but this is a function of the backwards compatibility design. Both powershell v1 and v2 run on CLR2. Powershell v3 runs on CLR4, so they bumped the strong name version to `3.0.0.0` for that one.

Just to confuse matters further, the windows folder name for all versions is v1.0 - again, for reasons of compatibility.

The only way you could actually be running the real powershell v1.0 is if you're on windows XP, vista or server 2003/2008. If you are running windows 7, 2008r2, you are on v2 at a minimum. If you are on 8 or 2012, you are on v3 of powershell at a minimum.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I guess that answers my question, though I'm on Windows Server 2008 R2, so it would still strictly be version 1.0 but for PowerShell 2.0. Oh well. Back to my [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051184/no-powershell-in-system-management-automation) on getting that `PowerShell` class to resolve.